# Drop down values are not getting listed in combobox in winform

Tags: c#, windows, combobox

I am using data grid control in windows application. I want to add one column as combo box which will load the drop down values from a data table.
below code I am using to create it.

```
                        DataTable Dt = new DataTable("Table1");
                        Dt.Columns.Add("Id");
                        Dt.Columns.Add("Value");
                        Dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "Item1" });
                        Dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "Item2" });
                        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
                        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "col1";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "col2";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "col3";
                        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                        cmb.HeaderText = "Item";
                        cmb.Name = "cmb";
                        cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;

                        cmb.DataSource = Dt;
                        cmb.DisplayMember = "Value";
                        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);



                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = reader[0].ToString();
                            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = reader[1].ToString();
                            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                            DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4]);
                            //ComboColumn.DataSource = Dt;
                            //ComboColumn.DisplayMember = "Value";
                            ComboColumn.Selected = true;
                        }
```

When i try to run this It gives me combo box with drop down but no values of item are loaded in it.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Why is the databinding commented out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compiled your code and it seems everything is working as intended!
[image: Result]

You can try a manual

```
 this.Refresh()
```

but I think your problem is somewhere else. Try a new visual studio project with the exact same code as above and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks marc... I tried it creating another winform.. The only thing i changed is removed the functionality from button click event and added in form_load and it worked out well.